# Google Places API Reviews Widget

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm trying to embed Google's "write a review" widget into my website. Much like what [Podium.com](https://www.podium.com/reviews/) does.

They host a page and load an iframe with the src:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/api/js/ReviewsService.LoadWriteWidget?key=THEIR_API_KEY&pb=!2m1!1sChIJ6VFjYpqa9YgREIJTX-XLyoE!3shttps%3A%2F%2Ftheir-url.com!5sen&cb=37369878
```

**This renders the widget like so:**
[image: Write a Review Widget]

I dug into their html source and it appears they're using the Google Places Reviews Widget. I searched [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=google.com+places+api+reviews+widget) and [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/s/results/?q=reviews+widget) for "Google Places Reviews Widget" which returns results:

[image: Search Result Listing]

**However, the links go to a 404 page:**

- https://developers.google.com/places/reviews/reference
- https://developers.google.com/places/reviews/widgets

I've replicated what Podium is doing on my own page using my API key. However, the widget doesn't display. I don't get any errors, the iframe loads some scripts and some hidden html elements, but doesn't render the full widget.

Is this an API or feature that I'm unable to access? Has anyone implemented something similar?

Comment: Maybe you can follow https://support.google.com/business/answer/7035772

Comment: @Hunter, Have you got any clue about this?

Comment: @Code_Crash nothing yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I also had the exact same experience and reached out to Google about it.

Here's their preliminary reply on Sept 4, 2018

> Apologies for the delay on this.
>
> May I ask if you followed the steps here:
>   https://developers.google.com/places/reviews/#api-key
>
> It says there that, "Before you begin coding, notify your Google
>   contact person that you intend to create a project to use the Google
>   Places API Reviews Widget. Indicate the email address of the Google
>   account you intend to use to manage the project. Google will use this
>   email address to allow you to activate the API for your project.
>
> After your Google contact person has confirmed that your email address
>   can activate the Google Places API Reviews Widget, you can follow the
>   instructions here:
>   https://developers.google.com/places/reviews/#api-key to activate the
>   API and create your key.
>
> May I ask if you have a contact person? If you don't have one,
>   apologies but the Review's Widget is not generally available, because
>   it needs some special authorization before it can be used. Please note
>   that we are investigating to see if you can get access to that Widget.
>
> If you do have a contact person, please let me know.
>
> Moving forward, may I ask what kind of places would you like to use
>   the Reviews Widget for?

Then this:

> With regards to your intention in using the Review Widget, I would
>   like you to know that unfortunately, the Review Widget is not
>   available at the moment yet. We don have a date for expected general
>   availability for this product but I can get back to you and inform you
>   once the Review widget is already available publicly. Once again,
>   apologies for this inconvenience.

And finally:

> The Reviews Widget is only actually limited to trusted partners as of
>   the moment. Moreover, the Review Widget team isn't looking for new
>   testers at the moment:
>
> With that said, the public documentation on the Reviews Widget has
>   already been set into private. As mentioned, the Reviews Widget is not
>   yet available for the general public.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news...

Comment: Just wondering if the situation has changed in regards to the Reviews Widget still being a trusted partners feature only? We are trying to do exactly what the OP has discussed.

Comment: Well, they didn't reach out to me to "let me know the widget is publicly available"... :-)  Does podium.com still offer the popup-style widget???

Comment: Podium is still doing it the "nice" way by embedding the form on their site so the user never navigates away.

I did get put in contact with somebody at google who assured me the API doesn't exist. When I pointed out that Podium is doing it I never heard back.

Answer (score 1):

check this out... I dunno if this helps.  i've been trying to figure this out too.  A company called BirdEye has this Review Portal that opens the post-review widget on the page.  I inspected the code and found that there are 2 JS scripts calling on Google's Places API (image attached).  The button code I'm assuming hitting these scripts is just below.  Does this make sense to anyone? I'm not able to get into the actual JS file though.

```
<button class="btnReviewSite2" data-source-url="https://www.google.com/search?q=Innovative+Roofing&amp;ludocid=8385655751686277266&amp;gws_rd=cr&amp;fpstate=lie&amp;lrd=0x87938c4de368e6b3:0x745fd57a1ff8c892,2#trex=m_t:lcl_akp,rc_f:nav,rc_ludocids:8385655751686277266" data-place-id="ChIJs-Zo402Mk4cRksj4H3rVX3Q" data-google-embedded="1" data-source-url_9="" data-source-id="2">
<span class="aggr-source-wrapper">
<span class="rev-site-2 presenceIcon aggr-source-2 aggr-dummy-source-g">
</span>
</span>
<span title="Review us on Google">
</span>
</button>
```

[Google Places API JS Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP77b.png)

Comment: Do you happen to have the URL to that review portal?